# Time change betwen requests from my winform

Tags: c#, winforms, http-post

I have winform wich read from file and make post request to web.Everything work perfectly, but I want to have one textbox where i can put time betwen every request.

for example:

I run my app and read whole file with(1000rows) and i make 2sec wait after every row. I use Thread.Sleep()must change it in code side every time if i want different value ... will be better to have options to change this from my form.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(TextBoxTime.Text));

Comment: Exaclty! Working perfectly. Thank you